# Is there ways to get line index when using like 'cat' and 'ls'?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-16.04

I am looking for ways getting line number when using especially 'cat'.

I tried this command on the ubuntu 16.04 like this

```
cat flux.log |grep "statistic"
```

And This is the results when finding out information.

```
 Using fit statistic: chi
 Using test statistic: chi
Fit statistic : Chi-Squared =         175.92 using 16 PHA bins.
Test statistic : Chi-Squared =         175.92 using 16 PHA bins.
Fit statistic : Chi-Squared =         175.92 using 16 PHA bins.
Test statistic : Chi-Squared =         175.92 using 16 PHA bins.
 Fit statistic in use: Chi-Squared
 Using fit statistic: chi
 Using test statistic: chi
Fit statistic : Chi-Squared =         175.92 using 16 PHA bins.
Test statistic : Chi-Squared =         175.92 using 16 PHA bins.
Fit statistic : Chi-Squared =           6.05 using 16 PHA bins.
Test statistic : Chi-Squared =           6.05 using 16 PHA bins.
Fit statistic : Chi-Squared =           6.05 using 16 PHA bins.
Test statistic : Chi-Squared =           6.05 using 16 PHA bins.
Fit statistic : Chi-Squared =           6.05 using 16 PHA bins.
Test statistic : Chi-Squared =           6.05 using 16 PHA bins.
Fit statistic : Chi-Squared =           6.05 using 16 PHA bins.
Test statistic : Chi-Squared =           6.05 using 16 PHA bins.
Fit statistic : Chi-Squared =           6.05 using 16 PHA bins.
Test statistic : Chi-Squared =           6.05 using 16 PHA bins.
Fit statistic : Chi-Squared =          66.15 using 16 PHA bins.
Test statistic : Chi-Squared =          66.15 using 16 PHA bins.
 Fit statistic in use: Chi-Squared
 Using fit statistic: chi
 Using test statistic: chi
Fit statistic : Chi-Squared =          66.15 using 16 PHA bins.
Test statistic : Chi-Squared =          66.15 using 16 PHA bins.
```

In this results, i want to last lines for catching information.

```
Fit statistic : Chi-Squared =          66.15 using 16 PHA bins.
Test statistic : Chi-Squared =          66.15 using 16 PHA bins.
```

the problem is there are many lines and these numbers that are written are random. So i just have information such as "Fit","Test","statistic" or "Chi-Squared" to finding.

If these results have line number and could get distinguished, i can be find the line i want to. Is there somebody help me?

ps, i have tried this command

```
<cat -n flux.log |grep "statistic">
```

but all of lines are different each file.

Comment: Can't you use the `tail` command?  `grep "statistic" flux.log | tail -2`.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `cat -n` and `grep -n` can both print line numbers; but often, requiring line numbers for the things you want to find is indicative of a more fundamental problem. A common antipattern is finding the matching lines so you can then delete them ... but you can delete them *when you find the match* just as well (`grep -v` or whatever), and the line numbers per se are completely unimportant and beside the point.

Comment: Also, as usual, avoid the abominable [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination `cat/grep` can usually be replaced with a singe `awk`.

In your case, you don't know when the last two occurrences would be as your file can span random number of lines. Try something like below:

```
$ awk '/statistic/{first= last;last="Line" NR " : " $0}END{print first RS last}'  casefile_48436615
Line27 : Fit statistic : Chi-Squared =          66.15 using 16 PHA bins.
Line28 : Test statistic : Chi-Squared =          66.15 using 16 PHA bins.
```

<sup>**Info :** The `awk` built-in `NR` gives the record number which indeed is the line number you're looking for. Also `RS` is the awk built-in for default record separator which is a newline. Using RS can help workaround hard-coding newlines in our script.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Try `man nl`. Also `awk '{print NR,$0}' myfile`